# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'midbottom'

Tags: python

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'midbottom'
Please help me out.

```
import pygame

class Ship:
  """A class to manage the ship."""
  
  def __init__(self,ai_game):
    """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()
    
    #Load the ship image and get its rect.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect
    
    #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
    self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
    
  def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at it's current location."""
    self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

Comment: `get_rect` is also a method, you have to call it with `()`

Comment: You need to learn basic syntax. Also, fix all your indentation.

Comment: I am a beginner sir following my project on course book i came across this problem. Indentation is perfect on my editor but I didn't got idea how question is posted on stackoverflow since its my first time.

Comment: Sir thank you for answering. Hope it works. But answers of the exercise of the book i am following has the same code as mine so i was worried.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at ["How to ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).